# How to create events using React Native

Tags: events, react-native, react-360

I'm making an application using [React VR](https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/). *If you don't know React VR, well it's based on React Native with some other components, includes Three.js and other stuff, specific for using WebVR.*

I've making a component named `NavigateButton`. Below is my code:

```babel
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, asset, StyleSheet, Pano, Text, View, VrButton, Sphere } from 'react-vr';

export class NavigateButton extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <VrButton onClick={() => this.onNavigating()}>
                <Sphere radius={0.5} widthSegments={10} heightSegments={10} style={{ color: "red" }} />
            </VrButton>
        );
    }

    onNavigating() { // This method must throw an event
        console.log(this.props.to); 
    }
};
```

If the user clicks on the `VrButton` *(this is like a HTML 5 `button`-tag but for VR with inside it, a sphere)*, an event must been raised to the place where I call the `NavigateButton` component. That's on code below:

```babel
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, asset, StyleSheet, Pano, Text, View, VrButton, Sphere } from 'react-vr';
import { NavigateButton } from './components/nativateButton.js';

let room = asset('360 LR/inkom_hal.jpg');

export default class MainComp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Pano source={asset('360 LR/inkom_hal.jpg')} />
                <View style={{ transform: [{ translate: [20, 0, 0] }] }}>
                    <NavigateButton to="garage"></NavigateButton> 
                    <!-- and must been catch here -->
                </View>
                <View style={{ transform: [{ translate: [-7, 0, -20] }] }}>
                    <NavigateButton to="woonkamer"></NavigateButton>
                    <!-- or here -->
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MainComp', () => MainComp);
```

Is it possible to do that? I would something like code below to catch the event:

```babel
<NavigateButton to="woonkamer" onNavigate={() => this.change()}></NavigateButton>
```

I've searched on the internet but nothing found that could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is the instruction how to create Sample VR app with React VR prepared by me and my team:**

Creating a VR tour for web
The structure of future app’s directory is as follows:

```
+-node_modules
+-static_assets
+-vr
\-.gitignore
\-.watchmanconfig
\-index.vr.js
\-package.json
\-postinstall.js
\-rn-cli-config.js
```

The code of a web app would be in the index.vr.js file, while the static_assets directory hosts external resources (images, 3D models). You can learn more on how to get started with React VR project here. The index.vr.js file contains the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
     AppRegistry,
     asset,
     StyleSheet,
     Pano,
     Text,
     View,
}
from 'react-vr';
class TMExample  extends React.Component {
     render() {
          return (
          <View> 
          <Pano source={asset('chess-world.jpg')}/>
               <Text
               style={{
                    backgroundColor:'blue',
                    padding: 0.02,
                    textAlign:'center',
                    textAlignVertical:'center',
                    fontSize: 0.8,
                    layoutOrigin: [0.5, 0.5],
                    transform: [{translate: [0, 0, -3]}],
               }}>
               hello
              </Text>
          </View>
          );
     }
};
AppRegistry.registerComponent('TMExample', () => TMExample);
```

**VR components in use**

We use React Native packager for code pre-processing, compilation, bundling and asset loading. In render function there are view, pano and text components. Each of these React VR components comes with a style attribute to help control the layout.

To wrap it up, check that the root component gets registered with AppRegistry.registerComponent, which bundles the application and readies it to run. Next step to highlight in our React VR project is compiling 2 main files.

**Index.vr.js file**

In constructor we’ve indicated the data for VR tour app. These are scene images, buttons to switch between scenes with X-Y-Z coordinates, values for animations. All the images we contain in static_assets folder.

```
constructor (props) {
     super(props);
    this.state =  {
      scenes: [{scene_image: 'initial.jpg', step: 1, navigations: [{step:2, translate: [0.73,-0.15,0.66], rotation: [0,36,0] }] },
               {scene_image: 'step1.jpg', step: 2, navigations: [{step:3, translate: [-0.43,-0.01,0.9], rotation: [0,140,0] }]},
               {scene_image: 'step2.jpg', step: 3, navigations: [{step:4, translate: [-0.4,0.05,-0.9], rotation: [0,0,0] }]},
               {scene_image: 'step3.jpg', step: 4, navigations: [{step:5, translate: [-0.55,-0.03,-0.8], rotation: [0,32,0] }]},
               {scene_image: 'step4.jpg', step: 5, navigations: [{step:1, translate: [0.2,-0.03,-1], rotation: [0,20,0] }]}],
      current_scene:{},
      animationWidth: 0.05,
      animationRadius: 50
      };
}
```

Then we’ve changed the output of images linking them to state, previously indicated in constructor.

```
<View>
    <Pano source={asset(this.state.current_scene['scene_image'])}
    style={{ 
         transform: [{translate: [0, 0, 0]}] 
    }}/>
</View>
```

Navigational buttons
In each scene we’ve placed transition buttons for navigation within a tour, taking data from state. Subscribing to onInput event to convey switching between scenes, binding this to it as well.

```
<View>
        <Pano source={asset(this.state.current_scene['scene_image'])} onInput={this.onPanoInput.bind(this)}
          onLoad={this.sceneOnLoad} onLoadEnd={this.sceneOnLoadEnd}
          style={{ transform: [{translate: [0, 0, 0]}] }}/>
        {this.state.current_scene['navigations'].map(function(item,i){
              return  <Mesh  key={i}
                            style={{
                                layoutOrigin: [0.5, 0.5],
                                transform: [{translate: item['translate']},
                                            {rotateX: item['rotation'][0]},
                                            {rotateY: item['rotation'][1]},
                                            {rotateZ: item['rotation'][2]}]
                            }}
                      onInput={ e => that.onNavigationClick(item,e)}>
                              <VrButton 
                                     style={{ width: 0.15,
                                            height:0.15,
                                            borderRadius: 50,
                                            justifyContent: 'center',
                                            alignItems: 'center',
                                            borderStyle: 'solid',
                                            borderColor: '#FFFFFF80',
                                            borderWidth: 0.01
                                     }}>
                                     <VrButton
                                            style={{ width: that.state.animationWidth,


    height:that.state.animationWidth,
                                                   borderRadius: that.state.animationRadius,
                                                   backgroundColor: '#FFFFFFD9'
                                            }}>
                                     </VrButton>
      </VrButton>
    </Mesh>
          })}
      </View>
onNavigationClick(item,e){
     if(e.nativeEvent.inputEvent.eventType === "mousedown" && e.nativeEvent.inputEvent.button === 0){
          var new_scene = this.state.scenes.find(i => i['step'] === item.step);
          this.setState({current_scene: new_scene});
          postMessage({ type: "sceneChanged"})
     }
}
sceneOnLoad(){
    postMessage({ type: "sceneLoadStart"})
  }

  sceneOnLoadEnd(){
    postMessage({ type: "sceneLoadEnd"})
  }
this.sceneOnLoad = this.sceneOnLoad.bind(this);
this.sceneOnLoadEnd = this.sceneOnLoadEnd.bind(this);
this.onNavigationClick = this.onNavigationClick.bind(this);
```

**Button animation**

Below, we’ll display the code for navigation button animations. We’ve built animations on button increase principle, applying conventional requestAnimationFrame.

```
                    this.animatePointer = this.animatePointer.bind(this);

animatePointer(){

var delta = this.state.animationWidth + 0.002;

var radius = this.state.animationRadius + 10;

if(delta >= 0.13){

delta = 0.05;

radius = 50;

}

this.setState({animationWidth: delta, animationRadius: radius})

this.frameHandle = requestAnimationFrame(this.animatePointer);

}
componentDidMount(){

this.animatePointer();

}
componentWillUnmount(){

if (this.frameHandle) {

cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameHandle);

this.frameHandle = null;

}

}
```

In componentWillMount function we’ve indicated the current scene. Then we’ve also subscribed to message event for data exchange with the main thread. We do it this way due to a need to work out a React VR component in a separate thread.

In onMainWindowMessage function we only process one message with newCoordinates key. We’ll elaborate later why we do so. Similarly, we’ve subscribed to onInput event to convey arrow turns.

```
componentWillMount(){
     window.addEventListener('message', this.onMainWindowMessage);
     this.setState({current_scene: this.state.scenes[0]})
}
onMainWindowMessage(e){
     switch (e.data.type) {
          case 'newCoordinates':
               var scene_navigation = this.state.current_scene.navigations[0];
               this.state.current_scene.navigations[0]['translate'] = [e.data.coordinates.x,e.data.coordinates.y,e.data.coordinates.z]
               this.forceUpdate();
          break;
     default:
          return;
     }
}
<Pano source={asset(this.state.current_scene['scene_image'])} onInput={this.onPanoInput.bind(this)}
         style={{ transform: [{translate: [0, 0, 0]}] }}/>
rotatePointer(nativeEvent){
     switch (nativeEvent.keyCode) {
           case 38:
                 this.state.current_scene.navigations[0]['rotation'][1] += 4;
           break;
           case 39:
                 this.state.current_scene.navigations[0]['rotation'][0] += 4;
           break;
           case 40:
                 this.state.current_scene.navigations[0]['rotation'][2] += 4;
           break;
           default:
                 return;
     }
     this.forceUpdate();
}
```

Arrow turns are done with ↑→↓ alt keys, for Y-X-Z axes respectively.

See and download the whole index.vr.js file on Github HERE.

**Client.js file**

Moving further into our React VR example of virtual reality web applications, we’ve added the code below into init function. The goal is processing of ondblclick, onmousewheel and message events, where the latter is in rendering thread for message exchanges. Also, we’ve kept a link to vr and vr.player._camera objects.

```
window.playerCamera = vr.player._camera;
window.vr = vr;
window.ondblclick= onRendererDoubleClick;
window.onmousewheel = onRendererMouseWheel;
vr.rootView.context.worker.addEventListener('message', onVRMessage);
```

We’ve introduced the onVRMessage function for zoom returning to default when scenes change. Also, we have added the loader when scene change occurs.

```
function onVRMessage(e) {
     switch (e.data.type) {
          case 'sceneChanged':
               if (window.playerCamera.zoom != 1) {
                    window.playerCamera.zoom = 1;
                    window.playerCamera.updateProjectionMatrix();
               }
          break;
          case 'sceneLoadStart':
             document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'block';
          break;
          case 'sceneLoadEnd':
             document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
          break;
          default:
               return;
     }
}
```

`onRendererDoubleClick` function for 3D-coordinates calculation and sending messages to vr component to change arrow coordinates. The `get3DPoint` function is custom to our web VR application and looks like this:

```
function onRendererDoubleClick(){
    var x  = 2 * (event.x / window.innerWidth) - 1;
    var y = 1 - 2 * ( event.y / window.innerHeight );
    var coordinates = get3DPoint(window.playerCamera, x, y);
    vr.rootView.context.worker.postMessage({ type: "newCoordinates", coordinates: coordinates });
}
```

Switch to mouse wheel

We’ve used the `onRendererMouseWheel` function for switching zoom to a mouse wheel.

```
function onRendererMouseWheel(){
     if (event.deltaY > 0 ){
          if(window.playerCamera.zoom  > 1) {
               window.playerCamera.zoom -= 0.1;
               window.playerCamera.updateProjectionMatrix();
          }
     }
     else {
          if(window.playerCamera.zoom < 3) {
               window.playerCamera.zoom += 0.1;
               window.playerCamera.updateProjectionMatrix();
          }
     }
}
```

Exporting coordinates

Then we’ve utilized Three.js to work with 3D-graphics. In this file we’ve only conveyed one function to export screen coordinated to world coordinates.

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
export function get3DPoint(camera,x,y){
    var mousePosition = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, 0.5);
    mousePosition.unproject(camera);
    var dir = mousePosition.sub(camera.position).normalize();
    return dir;
```

}

See and download the whole client.js file on Github HERE. There’s probably no need to explain how the cameraHelper.js file works, as it is plain simple, and you can download it as well.

Also, if you are interested in a lookalike project estimate or same additional technical details about ReactVR development - you can find some info [here](https://thinkmobiles.com/how-much-cost-create-react-vr-app/):